# hide home button and show only back button in actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I have tried so many ways like adding code in styles, setting mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

none of the ways i'm unable to hide home button, here how it looks i just need back button but i want to hide home button in actionbar is it possible?.

[image]

Comment: why not just change the resource of the "home button" to be your back button.

Comment: i'm not getting where to do that?, please give me a sample. i struggled lot i m not able to find place. please help me

Comment: `actionbar.setLogo(R.drawable.your_back_drawable);`

Comment: but for this do i need to enable mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);? also why do we add setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in styles, is it just to change back button i.e a small arrow?. So in my case since i need just a custom back image so simply replace using setlogo correct?

Comment: Yes. you can do it in styles or programatically I believe. Yes. Yes.